# Post object as JSon with Axios

Tags: javascript, rest, vuejs2, axios

I have an object named `entry` with properties `name`, `surname`, `age`.

I try to use `axios` to send this object  with `post` request to my REST server.

```
axios.post('http://host/myurl/myservice/',{data:this.ent})
```

However this fails with

> 400 Bad request

Because what is actually is being send is

```
 data: {data: {"name":"Jakob", "surname":"Laurence", "age":"25"} }
```

There is an extra `data` field which is not recognized on the server.

if I call

```
axios.post('http://host/myurl/myservice/',{
"name":this.entry.name, "surname":this.entry.surname, "age":this.entry.age 
})
```

Then everything works fine.

How can I post the entire object without axios generating extra **data** field, so that my server does not become confused?

Thanks.

P.S. All the above is going on in my Vue project (not sure if it's relevant).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direct pass the whole object:

```
axios.post('http://host/myurl/myservice/', this.ent);
```

Answer (score 1):

define the data as a constant before adding it to the axios url.

```
const postData = {
  name: this.entry.name,
  surname: this.entry.surname,
  age: this.entry.age
}
axios.post('http://host/myurl/myservice/', postData)
```